# Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in?

Tags: python, pycharm, psycopg2

when I run in Pycharm terminal `pip install psycopg2` it give me this error `Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\...` I tried a lot of thing that I found on stackoverflow but still not working. my pip version is 19.0.3 and my python version is 3.8

In the logs bellow it also says `Error: pg_config executable not found`

full logs when i try to pip install psycopg2

```
Collecting psycopg2
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/84/d7/6a93c99b5ba4d4d22daa3928b983cec66df4536ca50b22ce5dcac65e4e71/psycopg2-2.8.4.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info
    writing pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'

    Error: pg_config executable not found.

    pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
    containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
    option:

        python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

    or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

    If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
    'psycopg2-binary' package instead.

    For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
    <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html>).


    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ws21otxr\psycopg2\
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pip to install postgres client will attempt to build & install from source, which has additional dependencies as stated by the error message.

Go ahead and do 
    pip install psycopg2-binary
and you'll be on your way

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I just did ```pip install psycopg2-binary``` and got the same erorr

Comment: ```Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\tiber\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-e0fimblw\psycopg2-binary\``` same as the previous

Comment: Hmm - what version of Python and pip are you running? Are you installing in a virtual environment? In the meanwhile, try installing using Anaconda installer (conda install psyopg2) if you have it

Comment: Yes I am using a venz, my pip version is 19.0.3 and my python version is 3.8